# How does Rails build a MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have the following code that run on heroku inside a controller that *intermittently* fails. It's a no-brainer that it should work to me, but I must be missing something.

`@artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])`

The parameters hash looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"������",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Download",
 "action"=>"show",
 "controller"=>"albums",
 "artist_id"=>"62",
 "id"=>"157"}
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: : SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` WHERE `artists`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

notice the `WHERE`artists`.`id`= ?` part of the statement? It's trying to find an ID of QUESTION MARK. Meaning Rails is not passing in the `params[:artist_id]` which is obviously in the params hash. I'm at complete loss.

I get the same error on different pages trying to select the record in a similar fashion.

My environment: Cedar Stack on Heroku (this *only* happens on Heroku), Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.8, files being hosted on Amazon S3 (though I doubt it matters), using the `mysql` gem (not `mysql2`, which doesn't work at all), ClearDB MySQL database.

Here's the [full trace](https://gist.github.com/3756965).

Any help would be *tremendously* appreciated.

Comment: What's the result of `Article.find(42).to_sql` and `Article.find(params[:artist_id]).to_sql`?

Comment: What's the full error message? I suspect `Mysql::Error:` says more than just the problem query. (Also, the `?` isn't a problem -- it's a placeholder for a bound parameter.)

Comment: Please append the pertinent information from the trace to your question. If the link to it breaks your question will be missing important information. If there's nothing useful in the trace then remove the link.

Comment: Can you duplicate this problem on your dev box by connecting to the ClearDB database that you use on heroku? I wonder if it's some connectivity issue that only happens between heroku and ClearDB?

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate the problem on my dev box even by running the production environment that connects to cleardb, and (as heroku suggested) running using the `thin` server.

Comment: What do you mean by intermittently, does it always happen with album X or does it happen on any album but later on works on the same album?

Comment: Why doesn't the mysql2 gem work?

Comment: Can you run the commands @Mori suggested on heroku, using 'heroku run console' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### try sql?

If it's just this one statement, and it's causing production problems, can you omit the query generator just for now? In other words, for very short term, just write the SQL yourself. This will buy you a bit of time.

```
# All on one line:
Artist.find_by_sql
  "SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` 
   WHERE `artists`.`id` = #{params[:artist_id].to_i} LIMIT 1"
```

#### ARel/MySQL explain?

Rails can help explain what MySQL is trying to do:

```
Artist.find(params[:artist_id]).explain

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/
```

Perhaps you can discover some kind of difference between the queries that are succeeding vs. failing, such as how the `explain` uses indexes or optimizations.

#### mysql2 gem?

Can you try changing from the mysql gem to the mysql2 gem? What failure do you get when you switch to the mysql2 gem?

#### volatility?

Perhaps there's something else changing the params hash on the fly, so you see it when you print it, but it's changed by the time the query runs?

Try assigning the variable as soon as you receive the params:

```
artist_id = params[:artist_id]
... whatever code here...
@artist = Artist.find(artist_id)
```

#### not the params hash?

You wrote "Meaning Rails is not passing in the params[:artist_id] which is obviously in the params hash."  I don't think that's the problem-- I expect that you're seeing this because Rails is using the "?" as a placeholder for a prepared statement.

To find out, run the commands suggested by @Mori and compare them; they should be the same.

```
Article.find(42).to_sql
Article.find(params[:artist_id]).to_sql
```

#### prepared statements?

Could be a prepared statement cache problem, when the query is actually executed.

Here's the code that is failing-- and there's a big fat warning.

```
begin
  stmt.execute(*binds.map { |col, val| type_cast(val, col) })
rescue Mysql::Error => e
  # Older versions of MySQL leave the prepared statement in a bad
  # place when an error occurs. To support older mysql versions, we
  # need to close the statement and delete the statement from the
  # cache.
  stmt.close
  @statements.delete sql
  raise e
end
```

Try configuring your database to turn off prepared statements, to see if that makes a difference.

In your `./config/database.yml` file:

```
production:
   adapter: mysql
   prepared_statements: false
   ...
```

#### bugs with prepared statements?

There may be a problem with Rails ignoring this setting. If you want to know a lot more about it, see this discussion and bug fix by Jeremey Cole and Aaron: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7042

Heroku may ignore the setting. Here's a way you can try overriding Heroku by patching the prepared_statements setup: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5297

#### remove the query cache?

Try removing the ActiveRecord QueryCache to see if that makes a difference:

```
config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middle
```

#### try postgres?

If you can try Postgres, that could clear it up too. That may not be a long term solution for you, but it would isolate the problem to MySQL.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for the VERY thorough answer! After communicating with heroku back and forth, they suggested switching to the MySQL2 gem. I also had to change my `DATABASE_URL` under heroku config to use `mysql2://` rather than `mysql://` (something I forgot, and which caused this initial error with using the mysql2 gem). Switching to the `mysql2` gem solved the problem, and while heroku has no idea *why* this was happening, this solved the problem. Woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL statement is obviously wrong, but the Ruby code you mentioned would not produce it. Something is wrong here, either you use a different Ruby code (maybe one from a before_filter) or pass a different parameter (like params[:artist_id] = "?"). Looks like you use nested resources, something like `Artist has_many :albums`. Maybe the @artist variable is not initialized correctly in the previous action, so that params[:artist_id] has not the right value?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nested resources, as far as I know, had nothing to do with this, but looks like something was going wrong while building the MySQL statement.